# Python Dictionary Comprehension Loop

Tags: python, dictionary

So I've got the comprehension business working but **am wondering if there's a quicker way to do this than have a separate loop for each index**.

dR is a whole bunch of information loaded from a netCDF file and dN is preparing itself as a copy for interpolation.

```
dN = {  'lev'   : { i : dR['lev'][i] * 3.370079 for i in range(len(dR['lev'])) },
        'wdi'   : { i : dR['wdi'][i,::,1,1] for i in range(len(dR['tim'])) for o in range(len(dI['lev'])) },
        'wsp'   : { i : dR['wsp'][i,::,1,1] * 1.94384449 for i in range(len(dR['tim'])) for o in range(len(dI['lev'])) },
        'u'     : { i : dR['u'][i,::,1,1] * 1.94384449 for i in range(len(dR['tim'])) for o in range(len(dI['lev'])) },
        'v'     : { i : dR['v'][i,::,1,1] * 1.94384449 for i in range(len(dR['tim'])) for o in range(len(dI['lev'])) },
        'tim'   : dR['tim'][::3],
        'lon'   : dR['lon'][::].tolist(),
        'lat'   : dR['lat'][::].tolist()}
```

EDIT: So I've put a bunch of the indices together in a loop like so:

```
dN = { 'lev'   : dR['lev'][::] * 3.370079,
       'wdi'   : {},
       'wsp'   : {},
       'u'     : {},
       'v'     : {},
       'tim'   : dR['tim'][::3],
       'lon'   : dR['lon'][::].tolist(),
       'lat'   : dR['lat'][::].tolist()}

for i in range( len(dN['tim']) ):
    dN['lev'][i] = dR['lev'][i,::,1,1] * 3.370079
    for o in range( len(dI['lev']) ):
        dN['wsp'][i] = dR['wsp'][i,::,1,1] * 1.94384449
        dN['wdi'][i] = dR['wdi'][i,::,1,1] * 1.94384449
        dN['u'][i] = dR['u'][i,::,1,1] * 1.94384449
        dN['v'][i] = dR['v'][i,::,1,1] * 1.94384449
```

But am wondering if there's still a faster way to go about it, I find that it's a bit silly to have to declare each main indice and then manually apply to them after.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I'm getting the expected output, I just want to know if there's a faster way to do what I'm doing.

Comment: So we should tell you how to get from the input we don't know to the output we don't know faster?

Comment: Why use a dictionary in the first place?  numpy arrays are designed specifically for multi-dimensional data and work very well with netCDF files.

Comment: I'm using dictionaries because np arrays dont have a few members that I use and I'm too lazy to convert np array to list every time I need to.

Comment: Check out the method `getdefault` in class `dict`.  You could change lines such as `dN['wsp'][i] = something` to `dN.getdefault('wsp',{})[i] = something`.  Then you could drop the first five lines in your declaration of dN since the default values will be set the first time each element is accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I see from your code that dN['wsp'], dN['u'] and dN['v'] are exactly the same.  An obvious improvement is to build this dictionary once and copy it (or deepcopy if that makes more sense for the application).  But that has nothing to do with how comprehensions work, it's just good programming technique.  Are you trying to ask a more targeted question?

I also think that having dictionary comprehensions inside of a long dictionary declaration statement is hard to read.

Comment: Hi, sorry if my initial question seemed a bit vague I'll try to reiterate.

`dR = { i : { o for o in range( 0, 5 ) } for i in range( 0, 5 ) }`

So I'm doing that for a few indices in the dictionary and am wondering if theres a quicker way to do it than having 4 separate loops. I want to minimize lines of code so I'd rather do it all within the initial setup of the dictionary.

Comment: Your question was clear enough.  But which do you want, the quickest way or the shortest way?  If you want the quickest, do you really think that executing the same loop multiple times can possibly be right?  And why would you *ever* want to minimize the number of lines - how can that be a goal in any programming task?  Are you paying by the line for someone else to write it for you?

Answer (score 0):

You are using:

```
dR[someindex][i,::,1,1] * somefactor for i in range(len(dR['tim'])) for o in range(len(dI['lev']))
```

*Where somefactor is either 1 or 1.94384449*

A total of 4 times so you will probably get a big speed increase by first generating that dictionary once without the multiplier.